# Return the Sum and then Divide a Column in R

Tags: r, sum, dataframe, multiple-columns, divide

Suppose I have imported a csv data frame `df` that looks like:

```
        User    Lesson    Score
         A       1.1       6
         A       1.2       8
         A       3.1       9
         B       1.1       7
         B       3.6       9
         C       5.3       8
         C       6.3       9
```

I want to sum all of the scores by user, and then divide each of these "summed" scores by 5.
So that I get a data frame like:

```
        User        Score
         A           4.6
         B           3.2
         C           3.4
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: This is known as the "split-apply-combine" strategy and R is very good at it.  As such, there are a litany of posts related to this including many in the "Related" column to my right. `with(yourdata, tapply(Score, User, sum)/5)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `aggregate`:

```
> aggregate(Score/5 ~ User, df, sum)
  User Score
1    A   4.6
2    B   3.2
3    C   3.4
```

Comment: I get an error back "Error in as.data.frame.default(x) : cannot coerce class "formula" into a data.frame"

Comment: @user2543427 What is the output of `str(df)`? Which command did you use?

Comment: when I do str(df) i get:
'data.frame':1908 obs. of 3 variables:
$User:int 584...
$Lesson:Factor w/ 5 levels "1.1","1.2",...:1 1 1 ...
$Score:num 5 9 8 7 8 ...

all I typed was:
aggregate(Score/5~User,df, sum)

Answer (score 2):

I plain R you can use this:

```
aggregate(df$Score, by=list(User=df$User), function(x)sum(x)/5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per comments from @Justin try:

```
ddply(Users, .(User), summarise, sum(Score)/5) # I named your df "Users"
# User ..1
# 1    A 4.6
# 2    B 3.2
# 3    C 3.4
```